# SharePoint APP with list and pre-defined list item, error in specifying image URL

Tags: sharepoint-addin, splistitem

I am building a SharePoint hosted App which contains a list and pre-defined list items. When I try to deploy app, I get following error

> @"Error 1
>           CorrelationId: 39056be2-5dd1-4c51-ac43-9084a4791d02
>           ErrorDetail: There was a problem with activating the app web definition.
>           ErrorType: App
>           ErrorTypeName: App Related
>           ExceptionMessage: **Invalid URL: IMG SRC="../Images/Explore.png">.**
>           Source: AppWeb
>           SourceName: App Web Deployment
>   Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Failed to install app for SharePoint. Please see the output window for details.

[image]

I have also tried following but not working:

`<Field Name="BackgroundImageLocation">../Images/Explore.png</Field>`

Problem is in the URL of the background image location field.
How can I specify the URL of an image here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked.

```
<Field Name="Image">~site/Images/Explore.png</Field>
```